# How do I loop json.stringify so it update itself?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with using json.stringify. I have a on-click button with a function that adds another object into the var that holds the array.

```
var example = [{name: "K", age: 12},{name: "L", age: 12}];
var jsonE = JSON.stringify(example);
```

Whenever I add another object into the example, the value of jsonE doesn't not change.

Is there a way to constantly updating json because once you place an object into the array, and stringify "example", it cannot update itself? Is there a loop that I should be using?

***SOLUTION:***

make the JSON.stringify when on-click button is called

Comment: Why not call the JSON.stringify() method after adding all your objects to the array?

Comment: *"Is there a way to constantly updating json because once you place an object into the array..."* I sure hope not. That would be a confusing mess. You could create a custom object that manually manages this behavior for you, though I don't know why you'd want to keep updating the JSON instead of just updating it when you actually need it.

Comment: @squint  I am making a shopping cart at the moment, so when the user wants to add an item to the cart, the array updates itself from a function i made addItem(), I need to update JSON.stringify in order to pass the array to php and store into a session.

Comment: @User9123 that's an XY problem then. You don't _need_ to update the JSON, because you don't _need_ the JSON until you send it to the server. Stringify on save and that's it.

Comment: observables are a pattern regularly employed so that you can decouple operatoins and be notified when certain operations occur.  I posted a minimum example, lots about this, as it is a backbone of how dom events work

Comment: @vlaz So once the user wants to leave, I'll add the JSON there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JSON.parse to get the objects back and can add new object to it and again can stringify that.

```
var example = [{name: "K", age: 12},{name: "L", age: 12}];
var jsonE = JSON.stringify(example);
// get objects
var exampleParsed = JSON.parse(jsonE);
// add new object to var
exampleParsed.push({name: "M", age: 13});
// stringify new var
JSON.stringify(exampleParsed);

// output
"[{"name":"K","age":12},{"name":"L","age":12},{"name":"M","age":13}]"
```

See if this works for you (y).

Comment: That will only work for the first time, but thanks :D

Comment: @User9123 will work only first time? you mean If you are pushing new object in updated var it is no working?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to decouple the array from operations depending on it is to model the array as an [observable](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

To do this you could encapsulate the array as an observable, and then have the JSON.stringify dependency register a callback

```
function ObservableArray() {
   var self = this;
   this.onPushCbs = [];
   this.array = []
   this.push = function(value) {
     this.array.push(value)
     this.onPushCbs.forEach(function(cb) {
        cb(self.array);
     })
   }
}

var arr = new ObservableArray()
// ObservableArray {onPushCbs: Array[0], array: Array[0]}
// register event so every time that array is pushed to the value will
// be logged
arr.onPushCbs = [function(a) { console.log(a)}]
arr.push('1')
// logs ['1']
```